# How to get access to env variable of docker image inside of nextJS application

Tags: docker, next.js, environment-variables, argocd

I've set a docker env variable using Dockerfile and expected to get access to this value in the application, which is running inside the docker image (nextJS application).

I'm creating a docker image like this:

```
FROM node:20.0.0-alpine3.17
RUN apk add dumb-init

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ARG VERSION

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION $VERSION

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]
CMD npx next start
```

If I run docker inspect, I see the env variable is set:

```
"Config": {
    "Env": [
        "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
        "NODE_VERSION=20.0.0",
        "YARN_VERSION=1.22.19",
        "NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION=1.0.0",
    ],
}
```

I deploy the app using **argoCD**

In the app the version value (which is an env variable) should be displayed:

```
export const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Version {process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But the value is empty.

I guess I could set the version variable in the deployment mannifest, which is used by argocd:

```
spec:
    template:
        spec:
        containers:
            - name: app-name
            env:
                - name: NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION
                value: 1.0.0
```

But I do not understand why I do not have access to the env variable, which is set in the docker build step and which is existing in the docker image already.

Comment: just to be sure, your Footer is a Server Component?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem but used nextjs latest (13.4.19).
I did not encounter the same issue and my ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_VERSION wasn't empty.

You already tested if the ENV is set in your container (docker inspect ), so it might be a problem with NextJS. It is not a Docker issue.

Which NextJS are you using?

Comment: Running the app locally works. I do see the env var content. But in the dockerized app the var is not existing